# Consolidating & Collecting into one Record

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to write a cypher query where all related nodes are collected and returned under a key in a map:

```
{
    name: 'chart',
    CONTAINTED: [
        {
            name: 'id'
        },
        {
            name: 'bloodpressure'
        }, 
        ...
    ],
    FOREIGNKEY: [
        {
            name: 'clientid'
        }
    ]
}
```

[image: See Associated Picture For Example Graph]

I've attempted to do this with the following cypher query but it isn't quite right. Using the method below two records are returned rather than just one.

```
MATCH path=(table:tabPHI {name: 'client'})-[r]-(c)
WITH table as tab, type(r) as rel, collect(c) as col
CALL apoc.map.setKey(tab, rel, col) YIELD value as foo
return foo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MATCH (table:tabPHI {name: 'client'})-[r]-(c)
WITH table as tab, type(r) as rel, collect(c) as col
WITH tab, COLLECT(rel) AS keys, COLLECT(col) AS values
WITH keys(tab) as main_keys, [key IN keys(tab)|tab[key]] AS main_values, keys, values
CALL apoc.map.fromLists(main_keys + keys, main_values + values) YIELD value as foo
return foo
```

You're creating a single map for each relationship type in your query. You have to `COLLECT(rel)` at some point to get a single result for each tab.

Comment: That's perfect. I wish there was a simpler way to push these values into a map. That said this works very well.

Thank you!